# Dropping data frames from a list based on a condition?

Tags: python

I have a list of multiple data frames and I am trying to drop any data frames from the list that do not meet the condition, that they must have over 1000 unique ID's.

Each data frame is has few columns including ID, and a total of 14 data frames make up the list.

I found this code works for specific items in the list but wanted to find a better solution that does not require me to loop through items in the list:

`[i for i in list if list[0]['ID'].nunique() > 1000]`

All suggestions very welcome, thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "works for specific items in the list"? Also, there is nothing wrong with using a list comprehension for this application.

Comment: If you want to test the condition on every item in the list you inevitably have to loop over all items in the list in one way or another. The code you have shown is the clearest way to write that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think he wants to check if each df has more than 1000 unique entries. His current appraoch only checks for the first one in the list, because of `list[0]`

Comment: @Andreas - yes that's exactly right. I wanted to apply this to the whole list rather than a specific item in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, but all dfs need the column 'ID':

```
list_dfs_in = [df1, df2, df3]
list_dfs_out = []
for df in list_dfs:
    if df['id'].nunique() > 1000:
        list_dfs_out.append(df)

#print(list_dfs_out)
```

Or if you want to stick with your list comprehension you can do this:

```
list_dfs_in = [df1, df2, df3]
[df for df in list_dfs_in if df['ID'].nunique() > 1000]
```

Note: please try not to use native python names such as `list` rather give them names like 'lst'

Answer (score 2):

> find a better solution that does not require me to loop through items in the list

if you don’t wish to use looping, then a recursive function could achieve the same result as a loop.

```
def loop(df):
    if df['id'].nunique() > 1000:
         list_dfs_out.append(df)
         return loop(df + 1)
```